# How to include header only for the first page using enscript

Tags: enscript

I'm using enscript to produce a pdf file. I wish to include a header that contains the filename, like that

```
enscript --header='$n' ... file.py | ps2pdf - file.pdf
```

Every page of the resulted pdf includes a header with the filename. How can I have this header only on the first page of the pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that such option does not exist in enscript. I managed to achieve that by producing separate pdfs, one with the first page and a header and another with the rest of the pages and no header, and then combine them

```
enscript --output="-" --header='$n' --pages="1" "$infile" | ps2pdf - "$outfile.tmp1" # first page with header
enscript --output="-" --header='' --pages="2-" "$infile" | ps2pdf - "$outfile.tmp2"  # rest of the pages without header
pdftk "$outfile.tmp1" "$outfile.tmp2" cat output "$outfile"                          # concat results
rm "$outfile.tmp1" "$outfile.tmp2"
```